# How to enable nameserver recursion?

Tags: ubuntu, dns, resolv.conf, dig

On Ubuntu 14.04, when I'm performing a

```
dig google.de
```

on my machine, I get a `REFUSED` status (reducing to relevant lines):

```
me@machine:~# dig google.de
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 26926
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available
```

My `/etc/resolv.conf` knows three nameservers:

```
nameserver 1.2.3.4
nameserver 1.2.3.5
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

where the first two are corporate owned nameservers. But at least the last one (`8.8.8.8`) shouldn't return a refused status. So how can I enable recursion so that the last nameserver is considered?

Comment: Can you paste the `named.conf` configurations?

Comment: You should have `allow-query { any; };` in that

Comment: There is no `named.conf` on that machine; `find / -name "named.conf"` returns nothing...

Comment: That will be there on your nameserver..

Comment: Uh okay, sorry. Unfortunately I don't admin the nameserver.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The **DNS** resolver will only move onto the other name servers if the first one returns an error (i.e `SERVFAIL`) or can't be reached. If the **DNS** server returns `NXDOMAIN` then the resolver considers that the proper answer and won't check the others. `NXDOMAIN` is considered a final definitive answer that the requested domain does not exist.

In your case the first namserver is reached and is denying you.

In that namserver's `named.conf` you should have something like `allow-query { any; };`

#### Or

One solution might be to temporarily change the order of the nameservers in `/etc/resolv.conf` & put `8.8.8.8` first

#### Or

Just to direct `dig` to use `8.8.8.8` as the DNS server at command line you can do :

`dig @8.8.8.8 google.de`

Comment: Thank you! Do I have to restart something after modifying `resolv.conf` (and if yes: how)?

Comment: No, that's not necessary. It will be picked up immediately.

Comment: Funnily I still get the same behaviour. And although `8.8.8.8` is the first nameserver now, `dig` still returns `;; SERVER: 1.2.3.4#53(1.2.3.4)`...

Comment: @Neuron, you can specify a server for lookup in the dig command avoiding modifying files: `dig @8.8.8.8 google.de`

Comment: @YoMismo: Agree, edited my post to include your suggestion